Woodland Skipper in PA. Did these get blown here?
I have seen many woodland skippers this year in Eastern PA. Never seen them before. When I did a photo search I found their usual range is Western US. Have they recently migrated here or did they just get blown off course?
This one was in my garden. It's about one inch long.


What makes you think this is a Woodland Skipper specifically and not a related species? Here's a dichotomous key someone posted for your state on another site: https://bugguide.net/node/view/542311

You may well be right. These do look similar. When I searched for skippers in PA I didn't find any, only one list that mentioned skippers in the title, but when listing butterflies and skippers of PA did not include any. https://greennature.com/pennsylvania-butterflies/ Still, I wonder why these little crtitters have become so numerous this year. They have a very distinctive wing arrangement when resting with one set of wings flat and the other at a 45 degree angle. I've never seen them before.
